# JS не изменять контекст после самовызова

Tags: javascript

Нужно что бы функция продолжала работать в своем контексте:

```
function aaaa(v) {
    this.n = v;
    this.inscr = function() {
        this.n++;
    }
    this.bbbb = function(v) {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this.n);
        aaaa(5).inscr();
        console.log(self.n);
    }
    return this;
}
aaaa(1).bbbb();
```

Нужно что бы второй console.log(self.n) продолжил работать в своем же контексте
То есть первый и второй консоле.лог должны вывести один и тот же результат.
Можно ли обойтись без "new" ?

Comment: Вы понимаете, конечно, что в Вашем коде все `this` это `window`? "должны вывести один и тот же результат" - какой?

Comment: @Igor первый  консоле результат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function aaaa(v) {
    var result = {};
    result.n = v;
    result.inscr = function() {
        this.n++;
    }
    result.bbbb = function(v) {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this.n);
        aaaa(5).inscr();
        console.log(self.n);
    }
    return result;
}
aaaa(1).bbbb();
```

Answer (score 0):

В вызове `aaaa(1)` `this` устанавливается в `window` (в строгом режиме это `undefined`, были бы жертвы :)).
Т. е. в теле добавляются 3 переменных для `window` (число и две функции) и возвращается `window`.
Далее вызывается метод `window` `bbbb()`, который зачем-то сохраняет `this` в `self` (сохранение контекста нужно при его потери, в теле `window.bbbb` контекст не теряется);
выводит `window.n` (которое `1` после установки в `aaaa(1)`);
дальше происходит перезапись методов их копиями, но с новым значением `window.n`, которое теперь `5`, `inscr()`, очевидно, инкрементирует `window.n` (теперь это `6`);
выводится новое значение.

Вполне подходящее решение есть в ответе пользователя [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597974/207618), продублирую его:

```js
function aaaa(v) {
    var result = {};
    result.n = v;
    result.inscr = function() {
        this.n++;
    }
    result.bbbb = function(v) {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this.n);
        aaaa(5).inscr();
        console.log(self.n);
    }
    return result;
}
aaaa(1).bbbb();
```

На каждый новый вызов `aaaa` создаётся новый объект с индивидуальными параметрами (возможно, функции ссылаются на один объект, точно не знаю).

Comment: "каждый новый вызов aaaa создаётся новый объект" - точно знаю :)

Comment: @Igor, Вы-то знаете, но ТС может и не знает.